# Simple Ruby on Rails Button Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I have a method in a helper file that I want activated only when a button is pressed.

```
def add_f01
    @count = Count.find_by_user_id(@user)
    @car = Car.find_by_user_id(@user)

    @car.toggle!(:f01)
    @count.increment!(:v01)
end
```

How do I do it, please?

Comment: Do you want to access helper method from view?

Comment: Yes Emrah, I want to access a helper method that is include in the application_controller.rb from a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a working app here: https://github.com/noahc/stackoverflow

Pull it down and play around with it so you can learn how it works.

Essentially you need the following:

```
#routes.rb

match 'f01', to: 'users#call_app_controller'


# Anywhere in your view. I have it in index.html.erb of users
<td><%= button_to 'change name', f01_path(user: user)%></td>

#Application controller
def add_f01(user)
  user.first = "changed in Application Controller"
  user.save
end

 #users_controller
 def call_app_controller
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  add_f01(@user)
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Comment: I get this error undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x6448bd8>:0x64455a8>

Comment: What does the view and controller look like? You might have to change  user to @user, etc.

Comment: application_controller has include CarsHelper. helpers/cars_helper.rb has module CarsHelper

  def add_f01
    @count = Count.find_by_user_id(params[:user])
    @car = Car.find_by_user_id(params[:user])

    @car.toggle!(:f01)
    @count.increment!(:v01) view has <%= button_to 'Add f01', add_f01_path(user: user)%>  <i get user variable error> when i change it to <%= button_to 'Add f01', add_f01_path(user: @user)%> i get undefined method `add_f01_path'.

Comment: If you want to do it right, you'd probably do something like that.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but I don't know what to put in place for some_object and add_controller_path. Would you please put in exact names you would use and I can switch em up. Thanks

Comment: You need an object to call your methods on. So whatever model you put add_f01 in, you need an instance of that object. add_controller_path is the path to the controller action you put under `def controller`

Comment: Did you get it working Tony? I don't know exactly what you're trying to do so that makes it difficult to know how best to do it. The other option is leave it in application_controller and call it via add_f01(@user).

Comment: I didn't get it working yet. My goal is to get a button to execute some ruby code, that's basically it.

Comment: @TonyHassan See the update. I've added a git repo with working code. You should be able to pull it down and having it working quickly.